# Не стартует сервис qtservice

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Набросал свой сервис:
**myservice.h**

```
#ifndef MYSERVICE_H
#define MYSERVICE_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "QtService"

class MyService : public QtService<QCoreApplication>
{
public:
    MyService(int argc, char **argv);
    ~MyService();

    void start();
    void pause();
    void resume();
    void stop();
};

#endif // MYSERVICE_H
```

**myservice.cpp**

```
#include "myservice.h"

MyService::MyService(int argc, char **argv) : QtService<QCoreApplication>(argc, argv, "MyService1")
{
    try
    {
        setServiceDescription("This is my servise");
        setServiceFlags(QtServiceBase::CanBeSuspended);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        qDebug() << "An unknown error in constructor" ;
    }
}

MyService::~MyService()
{
    try
    {
//        setServiceDescription("This is my servise");
//        setServiceFlags(QtServiceBase::CanBeSuspended);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        qDebug() << "An unknown error in destructor" ;
    }
}

void MyService::start()
{
    try
    {
       QCoreApplication *app = application();
       qDebug() << "Service started...";
       qDebug() << app->applicationDirPath();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        qDebug() << "An unknown error in Start" ;
    }
}

void MyService::pause()
{
    try
    {
       qDebug() << "Service paused...";
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        qDebug() << "An unknown error in Pause" ;
    }
}

void MyService::resume()
{
    try
    {
       qDebug() << "Service resumed...";
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        qDebug() << "An unknown error in Resume" ;
    }
}

void MyService::stop()
{
    try
    {
       qDebug() << "Service stoped...";
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        qDebug() << "An unknown error in Stop" ;
    }
}
```

**test_agent.pro**

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test_agent
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    myservice.cpp

include(C:\Users\admin\Desktop\qtservice\src\qtservice.pri)
include(C:\Users\admin\Desktop\qtservice\common.pri)

HEADERS += \
    myservice.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <myservice.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
//    return a.exec();

    MyService service(argc, argv);
    return service.exec();
}
```

Сервис успешно устанавливается и удаляется если запускать его с ключами -i и -u
Но почему то на ключ -s отвечает

> The service MyService1 could not start

Запускаю всё из под QTCreator на **Windows 10**. Сам QTCreator запускаю от администратора. 
Сам сервис появляется в службах, но если запускать его из служб, то вылетает ошибка 1053.

> Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.

Саму библиотеку брал с офф. сайта https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions

Подскажите что я делаю не так? И как мне всё-таки запустить эту шарманку?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас не хватает в папке с исполняемым файлом библиотек qt-шных: если речь идёт о mingw, то это Qt5Core, libstdc++-6, libgcc_s_dw2-1 и libwinpthread-1 (возможно, что-то ещё, по зависимостям exe-шника надо глядеть). Служба должна запускаться от системного пользователя, если вы устанавливали её с ключом -i без передачи имени пользователя и пароля, а у него в PATH нет этих библиотек, вот и ругается.

Answer (score 1):

Запускай сервис с ключом -е. Все ключи прописаны в файле qtservice.cpp в int QtServiceBase::exec().